# ASP.NET MVC store Hebrew to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, hebrew

I have a form which pass a single data in hebrew, from the user (UI) to the SQL Server database.

For some reason the data stored in SQL Server like "???????".

If I go to the database and edit the value "???????" to the actual word in Hebrew, it saves it in Hebrew.

The field in the database is `nvarchar`

Why when the value pass trough the code to the database it stored like "??????" ?

cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Album</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AlbumName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AlbumName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AlbumName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="צור אלבום" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Albums/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "AlbumId,AlbumName")] Album album)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Albums.Add(album);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(album);
        }
```

Comment: For further help please include the EF version you are using, if its code first or using a designer, and if you are using fluent mapping or attribute based mapping. Finally include your `Album` model.

Answer (score 0):

In your SLQ Server database change the DataType of your column AlbumName:

```
var char(xxx) => nvarchar(xxx)
```

In Code First Apporach you should have Unicode set to True

[image]

Comment: @nirh1989 - then its probably your model mapping in EF.

Comment: @Igor - so how do i fix it?

Comment: Are you working in Code First Apporach, if yes try to re-generate table